# eclipse code/editor template for custom getter

Tags: java, eclipse, templates, field, getter

Is it possible to create an eclipse code/editor template for a getter of the type

```
public {field-type} {field-name:field}() {
    return {field-name};
}
```

where {field-type} is automatically resolved using the entered {field-name:field} field name?

Example:

```
private String name;

public String name() {
    return name;
}
```

Comment: your method `name()` not resolved as a *getter*, `getName()` is best for this.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Ctrl+Space` while editing the template to get a list of built-in variables.  {field-type}  or anything like that is not part of it.

Note that you are not following code conventions with that template.

*By convention, method names should be a verb in lowercase or a multi-word name that begins with a verb in lowercase, followed by adjectives, nouns, etc. In multi-word names, the first letter of each of the second and following words should be capitalized. ([Java Tutorial, Defining Methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html))*